# Angular Custom Form Control - Get default value

Tags: angular

I have a custom control which uses “ControlValueAccessor” - “registerOnChange” callback to send the value to the parent form whenever the value of the form control changes. No problem here.

But I also want to send the default value which I set for the custom control during OnInit. The problem is the “registerOnChange” callback happens only after OnInit.

Is there a way around ?

Comment: You already have default value as you are setting it up. Why can't you use that?

Comment: Doesn't the added answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ngAfterViewInit()` will be called after the `registerOnChange` method runs.

You can programatically set the value of the input here but that would not call the registered `onChange()` method(say the name is onChange). You will need to explicitly call it. Now the problem comes by the " ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError".

The problem is the check can happen in the parent component too if there are bindings to the child control there. Calling a `detectCahnges()` will only check the changes in the current component and its children. Doing a `markForCheck()` will mark this and its ancestors for check in next change detection but will not call change detection immediately. If nothing helps, a `setTimeout()` will definitely.

You can have something like:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.value = "changed value";
      this.onChange(this.value)
    })
  }


<input 
  [value]="value"
  (input)="onChange($event.target.value)"
  (blur)="onTouched()"
  [disabled]="isDisabled"
  type="text">
```

See an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/controlvalueaccessorgeneric-srsut9?file=src/app/app.component.ts

But again, why do you need to do this? You can always give the initial form control values while you are initializing the Reactive form.

Comment: Thanks. I am handling it with setTimeout as you have suggested. I need it, as my custom control inherently have a value even if not getting initialised

Comment: @Muthukumar Got it! Thank you for accepting the answer! :)