# Angular ValueChanges not updating parent form (ControlValueAccessor)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I have the following code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-control-value-accessor-form-submitted-val-egkreh?file=src/app/app.component.html

I have passed in default values for the form fields, but they are not reflected in the parent form if you click the button

```
  private createFormInstance() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      username: ['test', [Validators.required]],
      password: ['test', [Validators.required]],
    });
  }
```

If you click submit without modifying any of the input fields, i would like for the default values to appear, but instead i get `null`. I only see data if I modify the input fields, but I also have a scenario where I need to submit the form passing in default values without the need to modify

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Think that your scenario is similar to this question: [Angular Custom Form Control - Get default value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55844456/8017690).

For your case, after the custom form is rendered, with the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook to trigger

```
this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
```

This will update the nested form and pass its default value to the parent form.

```
import { AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

export class LoginFormComponent
  implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  ...

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
    })
  }
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-control-value-accessor-form-submitted-val-4ytx5w?file=src/app/login-form/login-form.component.ts)